# Android cannot resolve method onViewCreated(android.view.View, android.os.Bundle)

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        /** Restore the previously serialized activated item position. */
        if (savedInstanceState != null
                && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
            setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState
                    .getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
        }

        /** Set Button OnClickListener */
        Button btnClass = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonClassification);
        btnClass.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

I keep getting this error. Tried to resolve it without success. Can someone explain the reason for this error?

The class extends ListFragment and implements OnClickListener.

Comment: This is in a fragment class, yes?

Comment: make sure your class `extends Fragment`

Comment: can you post the complete class code?? Two things to check you have extended the fragment class and not trying to override the functions in same class.

Comment: I've updated the question. And onViewCreated() method is overidden only in here

Comment: add the complete code

Comment: If your class extends ListFragment, then the only thing I can think of is that your android SDK is not properly configured within your IDE. Nothing else would cause a resolution error (not even overriding functions in the same class. That would show up as a different error)

Comment: I newly setup android studio. I think problem is with android studio. What part of configuration isn't proper? I added necessary jar files to the project.

Comment: I commented all the calls of that method and removed all the override. Then all classes compiles fine. But when I run the project I get, Error:Android Source Generator: [votesmanager] AndroidManifest.xml file not found

Comment: @user11 I'm starting to think that this is your first android project? You should try to use Android studio because it removes a lot of the potential pitfalls you can have when making an android project such as missing gradle files, androidmanifest.xml files, missing or misconfigured android sdks, etc. You can get android studio here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: I'm already using android studio

Comment: @user11 unfortunately, without seeing more of your project I cannot help you further, then. There are too many little things that can do wrong with configuration and it seems that something is screwed up configuration-wise with your project.

Comment: I see. Thanks anyway. I'll try to reconfigure